# bigqueryで2つのマスタからユニークkeyを作りたい

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

bigqueryというよりも、sqlの初歩的な質問になると思うのですが、
下記について困っています。

以下のような2種類のテーブルがあります。
①T_DATE
DATE,
2019-01-01
2019-01-02
2019-01-03
・・・

②T_PRODUCT
PRODUCT,
A
B
C
・・・

この種類のマスタテーブルから、
以下のようなテーブルを新規で作りたいです。
③T_DATE-PRODUCT
DATE,PRODUCT
2019-01-01,A
2019-01-02,A
2019-01-03,A
2019-01-01,B
2019-01-02,B
2019-01-03,B
2019-01-01,C
2019-01-02,C
2019-01-03,C
・・・

要は、DATE×PRODUCTユニークのテーブルを作りたいです。
（いまはいちいちEXCELでお手製マスタを作っているのですが、SQLで完結させたいです）

良きやりかたを教えていただけますと幸いです。

何卒お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

意図が違うような気がしますが、回答してみます。

T_DATEとT_PRODUCTテーブルが存在する際に以下のSQLでT_DATE_PRODUCTテーブルに指定の値を設定可能です。

```
insert into T_DATE_PRODUCT select * from T_DATE, T_PRODUCT;
```

---

以下蛇足です。
T_DATEとT_PRODUCTが変更された場合に、毎回T_DATE_PRODUCTを作り直す必要があるため、viewの方がよい気がします。
以下のSQLで作成が可能です。

```
create view V_DATE_PRODUCT as select * from T_DATE, T_PRODUCT;
```

---

実行SQL

```
drop table if exists T_DATE;
drop table if exists T_PRODUCT;
drop table if exists T_DATE_PRODUCT;
create temp table T_DATE(date date);
insert into T_DATE values('2019-01-01'),('2019-01-02'),('2019-01-03');
create temp table T_PRODUCT(product varchar(100));
insert into T_PRODUCT values('A'),('B'),('C');
create temp table T_DATE_PRODUCT(date date, product varchar(100));

insert into T_DATE_PRODUCT select * from T_DATE, T_PRODUCT;
select * from T_DATE_PRODUCT;
drop view if exists V_DATE_PRODUCT;
create view V_DATE_PRODUCT as select * from T_DATE, T_PRODUCT;
select * from V_DATE_PRODUCT;
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！まさにコレがやりたかったことです！[select * from T_DATE, T_PRODUCT]でユニークKEYが作れるのを知らなかったでのたすかりました！